# Golang visibility or CPU thread cache issue

Tags: go, concurrency, volatile

1) How does golang solve visibility issue?

2) Is there any issues with below code?

```
package main

type Service struct {
    stop bool
}

func (s *Service) Run() {
    for !s.stop {
        //Some logic
    }
}

func (s *Service) Stop() {
    s.stop = true
}

func main() {
    s := &Service{}
    go s.Run()
    //Some logic
    s.Stop()
}
```

Comment: Your code is woefully incomplete. It's hard to judge whether it has any issues beyond that.

Comment: 1) Memory fences, by use of mutexes golang.org/pkg/sync{/atomic} As for 2) Yes, use channels, mutexes, or atomics

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for your comment, added Stop function

Comment: @Maksym Yes. It has a data race. Besides, your main goroutine (executing main) runs to end and kills off the other goroutine in the process.

Comment: "How does golang solve visibility issue?" What do you mean by "visibility issue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [context.WithCancel](https://godoc.org/context#CancelFunc) to stop goroutines in this case.